# document.querySelectorAll doesn't work in cypress running with chrome 80

Tags: javascript, dom, automated-tests, cypress

When executing document.querySelectorAll in the chrome DOM it is returning the values ​​normally however when executing as a function in cypress the document.querySelectorAll always returns me empty.

```js
const itensText = []
  const url = area => cy.url().should('contain', area)
  const arrayItens = () => {
    const itensCount = document.querySelectorAll("*[data-cy='areas-item']").length
    console.log(itensCount, 'contador');
    for(var i=0; i<itensCount; i++) {
      itensText.push(document.querySelectorAll("*[data-cy='areas-item']")[i].innerText);
    };
  }
```

```html
<ul data-cy="areas-holder" class="styled__AreasHolder-kUDyGB leBHiV"><li data-cy="areas-item" class="styled__AreasItem-ejSxag jdRdwx"><a data-cy="Oncogenética" class="styled__AreasItemLink-yXJfI jaazQV" href="/exames?area=Oncogenética"><svg class="styled__AreasItemIcon-iWyosv kXRKoO"><use xlink:href="#gene-mutation"></use></svg>Oncogenética</a></li><li data-cy="areas-item" class="styled__AreasItem-ejSxag jdRdwx"><a data-cy="Doenças Raras" class="styled__AreasItemLink-yXJfI jaazQV" href="/exames?area=Doenças Raras"><svg class="styled__AreasItemIcon-iWyosv kXRKoO"><use xlink:href="#petri-dish"></use></svg>Doenças Raras</a></li><li data-cy="areas-item" class="styled__AreasItem-ejSxag jdRdwx"><a data-cy="Neurogenética" class="styled__AreasItemLink-yXJfI jaazQV" href="/exames?area=Neurogenética"><svg class="styled__AreasItemIcon-iWyosv kXRKoO"><use xlink:href="#genome"></use></svg>Neurogenética</a></li></ul>
```

Chrome DOM

[image]

Crypress with Chrome 80 DOM

[image]

I need to build an array with the values ​​of each item, to use in a future scenario test

Comment: What do you get when you console.dir() the returned object of the queryselectorall method?

Comment: @KingKabyle, `console.dir(document)` ou `console.dir(document.location)` return _undefined_

Comment: Please tell me output of console.dir(document.querySelectorAll("*[data-cy='areas-item']"))

Comment: ok, it return _undefined_ too

Comment: On your screenshot I can see that you where check the length of the NodeList which return a zero. So the result of the querySelectorAll can't be undefined, because the "length" of undefined is NOT 0. Please check!

Comment: I take a new ss, pls see the link https://imgur.com/IpgSs1n

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208669/discussion-between-vini-gabriel-and-kingkabyle).

Answer (score 13):

To access your test page's document, you should use the [cy.document() command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/document.html#Examples) to obtain a reference. The document you access as a global belongs to the Cypress runner, but the test page is inside an iFrame which has a different document reference.

```js
cy.document().then((doc) => {
  const itensCount = doc.querySelectorAll("*[data-cy='areas-item']").length
  ...
})
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer !
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/document#Syntax